# How to get map variable of Json using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am stuck with an issue of parsing data from an array using jquery. Kindly guide me to fix the issue.

```
var json = '{ "menu1": ["City1", "City2", "City3"], "menu2": ["City1", "City2"] } ';
var arr = $.parseJSON(json);
console.log(arr);
```

**output:**
undefined

**Expected ouput:**

```
Menu1: ["City1","City2","City3"]

Menu2: ["City1","City2"]
```

How do I parse the values for the key `menu1` from the above `json`?

Comment: this is not a proper json format

Comment: Valid json format is `{
 "menu1": ["City1", "City2", "City3"],
 "menu2": ["City1", "City2"]
}`

Comment: @Mohammad - I changed the json format as you mentioned above. Now how do I parse the value for "menu1".

Comment: for menu1 `arr.menu1` would output `["City1", "City2", "City3"]`, also consider `arr.menu1[0]` would output `"City1"`

Comment: @Mohammad the format you commented, is it also valid for json string ? Won't there be some escape sequences in that ? I am not sure. Just want to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `.` operator to access the fields after parssing json

```js
var json = '{ "menu1": ["City1", "City2", "City3"], "menu2": ["City1", "City2"] } ';
var arr = $.parseJSON(json);
console.log(arr.menu1);
console.log(arr.menu2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

```js
var json = '{ "menu1": ["City1", "City2", "City3"], "menu2": ["City1", "City2"] } ';

/* JSON.parse is fine to parse data in browser without using jQuery. */
var arr = JSON.parse(json);
console.log('All menus', arr);

/* You can access values in any of the way dot(.) or bracket([]) notation. */
console.log('Menu 1', arr.menu1, arr['menu1']);
console.log('Menu 2', arr.menu2, arr['menu2']);
```